# how to return a private field in list?

Tags: java, list, object, field, dao

Hello I would like to know how to get "rolesArrayDataSource" and return it because i need to return him in "List "

```
public class ManualArrayRoleDao /*extends AbstractArrayDao<Role>*/ implements IRoleDao {

private static final Log log = LogFactory.getLog(ManualArrayRoleDao.class);
private Role[] rolesArrayDataSource = null;

//public ManualArrayRoleDao() {
//    super(Role.class, DataSource.getInstance().getRolesArrayDataSource());
//}
/**
 * Méthode qui retourne la liste de tous les rôles de la database (ici
 * rolesArrayDataSource)
 *
 * @return La liste de tous les rôles de la database
 */
@Override
public List<Role> findAllRoles() {
    field allRole = ManualArrayRoleDao.class.getDeclaredField("rolesArrayDataSource");
    return allRole;
}
```

Comment: Why not just do `return Arrays.asList(rolesArrayDataSource);`? I'm not sure what you are trying to do and why you are playing around with reflection...

Comment: because i'm a beginner thanks you for helping me